# How do I stop DBI connect from adding @localhost to my username?

Tags: perl

This is a newbie question - don't overthink it!

I'm trying to make a connection from perl to a remote server's MySQL database that I can connect to just fine from PHP or from TOAD, so I know clearly what my host, dbname, username and password are.

But when I try to do this from my new installation of Strawberry Perl using the Padre IDE, something somewhere ( probably some config file ?) keeps insisting on adding '@localhost' to my username.

Oh, I'm using perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for  MSWin32-x86-multi-thread.
I'm trying:

```
my $DBHOST = "50.88.64.41";
my $DBNAME = "keystrokes";
my $DBUSER = "wade\@'50.88.64.41'";
...
# MySQL database configuration
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$DBNAME,host=$DBHOST,port=3306";
```

So I get this output ( slightly sanitized for privacy):

DBI connect('database=keystrokes,host=50.88.64.41,port=3306','**wade@50.88.64.41**',...) failed: Access denied for user '**wade@50.88.64.41'@'localhost**' (using password: YES) at C:\Bitnami\wampstack-8.0.8-0\apache2\htdocs\perl\firstscript.pl line 2.

Whether I put in my username as "wade" or as "wade@50.88.64.41" or "wade@'50.88.64.41'" SOMETHING then adds "@'localhost' to it, then tries to use that as the username, which of course fails, because I'm not on that machine and it is not my localhost.

Any ideas how to fix this? I couldn't find any explicit answers in this forum.
Thank you!

Comment: I believe DBI DSN strings take _semicolon_ separated attributes, not _comma_ separated.  Try `DBI:mysql:foo=bar;baz=buz;quux=fugazi`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is the exact opposite of what you think it is. MySQL is doing the right thing by adding '@localhost' to your username. What you don't need is the `@50.88.64.41' that you add. I've been connecting Perl programs to MySQL databases for fifteen years and I've never needed to add something like that to a username.

The '@host' that you'll see in MySQL connection messages is added by the MySQL client library when making the connection - by looking at the IP address that the connection request is coming from.

So just change your code to:

```
my $DBUSER = 'wade';
```

and it should work.

Traditionally, you'll see two rows for each user in the `mysql.user` table. One with a host of `localhost` and the other with a host of `%` (which means "any other host"). That makes it easier to control access to the database - it's common that you would only allow access to users who are on the same server as database.

Comment: Both Pilcrow's comment and your answer were required.  I needed to change the commas to semicolons in the $dsn string.  THEN also remove the @... stuff. Then it  works!  Thank you both!